# Multiple Boolean Expressions in Case When statement

Tags: sql-server

Below is the part code that I am trying to make work... Essentially it will give me the date of the  previous Monday if today is Monday. If today is not Monday then it will give me the date of the Monday of this week.

```
WHERE
CASE WHEN
DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) = '1' 
THEN
DateColumn >= DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()) - 1,0)
ELSE
DateColumn >= DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()),0)
END
```

However, when I run the code it says there is an incorrect syntax near '>'. I am not sure if it doesn't like me using multiple Boolean expressions or if there really is something wrong with that syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the syntax slightly wrong; it should be:

```
WHERE
 DateColumn >= 
  CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) = 1 -- datepart returns an integer, so no quotes
   THEN DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()) - 1,0)
   ELSE DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()),0)
  END
```

Comment: Thanks! I will be using this a lot more now that I know how to properly set it up!